# go-mtpfs and Android Mounting problem

Tags: mount, android, samsung, mtp

I had real problems mounting my samsung Galaxy S3 Neo on Ubuntu 12.04, one lucky random day and it mounts and then for several days it doesn't then again randomly for once does ! This had been going on then I found really a great solution: go-mtpfs

I named the mount point as "andro3" and I have been using the command:

go-mtpfs-u /media/andro3

and to unmount:

fusermount -u /media/andro3

It was working flawlessly... and I was so happy, then I went for a 10 day trip and left my connecting cable at home ! During that trip I updated my system maybe 3 times with:

sudo apt-get update

and

sudo apt-get  dist-upgrade

When I came back home after the 10 day trip, I discovered that once again the problem seems to be back, go-mtpfs won't work !!!

Whenever I typed the command:

go-mtpfs /media/andro3

It will say,

"

2015/08/21 04:06:29 compiled against libmtp 1.1.5
Device 0 (VID=0*** and PID=***0) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
2015/08/21 04:06:29 found device Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (0***:***0) @ bus 3, dev 55
:

"

And then if I try to unmount anyway (even if it's not mounted) by using :

fusermount -u /media/andro3

It says:

fusermount: entry for /media/andro3 not found in /etc/mtab

Which is quite obvious !

I have replaced some characters by * I don't know if that was necessary for the security point of view or not but I just did. Anyway, any idea what might have happened in these 10 days ? Anything to do with the updates that I did ?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to an unity release that has mtp mounting working from the beginning? Like 14.04 or 15.04.

Comment: Hi xangua, thanks for the suggestion but I find upgrades a bit disturbing, I had bad experiences.. upgrades often results in disasters. But I am planning for a new install of a new release.. not at the moment though.

Comment: And what about this, instead of manually mounting using go-mtpfs? Worked for me back in 12.04. http://m.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html?m=1

Comment: Just now tried that.. didn't work !

Comment: It automatically detects the mobile and says it's connected but when I click on that an error message pops up "Unable to mount Samsung_android / Unable to open mtp device '[usb:003,007]' " !! (Referring to Xangua's last suggestion)

Comment: Once again suddenly this evening it automatically opened in the nautilus !